# PYTHONSTARTUP equivalent for remote_api_shell.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Every time I use the remote api shell, I end up importing and running 80% same code, and then doing what I need.

I'm wondering if there is a default way to specify a series of imports/commands for every time I use it.